# Why do $I,J,P$ still need confirmation for the B mesons?

Tags: standard-model, mesons

If I open the PDG (say [here](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/tables/contents_tables_mesons.html)), and look at the quantum numbers of the $B$ mesons it says, for every $B$ meson, "I, J, P need confirmation". However, this disclaimer doesn't appear for any other type of meson as far as I can tell (though I just did a quick glance around). It would seem straightforward to measure these quantum numbers through its decay products though presumably this doesn't qualify as a measurement.

What would constitute as a measurement of this? Furthermore, is there a reason why this measurement hasn't been done for the $B$ system while it has been done for the $D$'s or have the PDG-writers just not bothered to include this disclaimer everywhere?

Answer (score 2):

To find those quantum numbers experimentally, and this is true for any particle, one normally looks at decay processes and then rely on the knowledge of the quantum numbers for the decay products (for spin, one has to take into account the orbital momentum of those as well), **assuming those quantum numbers are preserved by the interaction at work in the decay**. The archetypical example is $\pi^0$. By using $\pi^0\to 2\gamma$, and observing the polarisations of the photons, one can deduce that the parity of $\pi^0$ is -1. This is made possible by the fact that the interaction here is just QED and therefore parity is conserved.

But B mesons decay through the weak interaction, which breaks parity and isospin. So it is not possible to infer the parity and isospin of the B meson from mere experimental observations. For J, I can't remember from the top of my head.

Comment: Determining $J$ usually requires measuring correlations in the emission angles of the decay products.  That means you need good statistical power (many events) in *many* detectors, while you can say "there's a particle at this mass" based on good statistics in fewer detectors.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do agree you need a quantum number to be preserved by an interaction to have a meaningful measurement of that quantum number. However, this still doesn't explain why such numbers would have been measured for all the other non-quarkonium states. In particular the disclaimer doesn't appear for the D and K mesons, both of which can only decay weakly. Maybe this is just a mistake in the PDG?

Comment: For J, I think @rob is in the right direction. Kaons decays result in simpler final states (leptons, pions, photons), and we have a far better statistics. To a lesser extent, this arguments applies to D mesons too I think (decay products are Kaons and pions).

Comment: For P, I am not sure why it would be so much more difficult than for K and D mesons. Perhaps the reason lies in the fact that direct CP violation is weak in those two sectors. After all, we can even discriminate CP eigenstates of Kaons very well. My guess is that the near conservation of CP for decays of $K_S$ and $K_L$ enables to infer their CP, from which one can infer their parity. Whether the same idea explains it for the D mesons, I don't know.